# How to handle email bounce and Email limit exceeded in salesforce using apex

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, unit-test, community

How to handle email bounce and Email limit exceeded in salesforce. I am new in salesforce. I try too much but can not rid-off. So how to handle these problems.

Answer (score -1):

for getting bounce back message we can use email deliverablity in email adminstration and we can use this and make this happen if i am wrong could you please precisely post your requirement

Comment: Yes , i have a list of email. there is a wrong email address in it. i want to send email message to other address by avoiding wrong address in the list. so how can i do?

Comment: under email adminstration we will have email deliverability select that then you do the required configuration it works then